# Polymer href link anchor does not scroll to div when using <iron-pages>

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer 1.x, and I have an `<iron-selector>` with generated links. I would like for one of my links to scroll to a `<div>`. However, I cannot achieve this successfully as the link is intercepted by the `<iron-pages>`. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<iron-selector role="navigation" class="drawer-list" selected="[[categoryName]]" attr-for-selected="name">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[categories]]" as="category" initial-count="4">
        <a name="[[category.name]]" href="[[category.link]]">[[category.title]]</a>
    </template>
</iron-selector>

<section id="contactSection" class="home-contact ss-style-triangles">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-wrap">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404">
  <!-- home view -->
    <cass-home name="home"></cass-home>
    <cass-why name="whyChooseUs" route="{{subroute}}"></cass-why>
    <cass-partner name="partner" route="{{subroute}}"></cass-partner>
    <cass-404-warning name="404"></cass-404-warning>
</iron-pages>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
var categoryList = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        title: 'Accueil',
        link: '/home',
    },
    {
        name: 'home',
        title: 'Home',
        link: '/home',
    },
    {
        name: 'b2b',
        title: 'Company',
        link: '/b2b',
    },
    {
        name: 'login',
        title: 'Connection',
        link:'/login'
    },
    {
        name: 'contact',
        title: 'Contact',
        link:'javascript:document.querySelector("#contactSection").scrollIntoView();'
    }
  ];
```

The  is linked to an  to set the core part of my

However, as it is in the local DOM, it's not detecting the `#contactSection`. I also tried using a function and registering a listener, but unsuccessfully.

Any hints?

Comment: Please update the question to show the full context of how you've "linked to `<iron-pages>`" and how that affects your anchor. I don't quite understand what you're saying, but the code might be clearer.

Comment: sorry, I'll update

Comment: I think he meant, where is the above code in relation to the `iron-pages` element.

Comment: I added more information. When clicking a link, the app-location is changed. Therefore, the iron-pages will try to match the current link (say #contactSection") with one of the entries name (e.g "home")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround that problem by imperatively scrolling the `<div>` into view with a [listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) on the anchor's `tap` event:

```
<a href="#aboutSection" on-tap="_onTapAnchor">About</a>
<a href="#contactSection" on-tap="_onTapAnchor">Contact</a>

// <script>
_onTapAnchor: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var anchor = e.target.attributes.href.value;
  this.$$(anchor).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Notes:

- `e.target` is the `<a>` tag, which has an `attributes` map, containing the raw value of `href` (`#contactSection` as opposed to `http://localhost:8080/#contactSection`).
- We take `e.target.attributes.href.value` (e.g., `#contactSection`) and query the local DOM for it with [`this.$$(...)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#instance-methods) -- shorthand for `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(...)`.
- We then take the result of the previous call (which is a `<div>`), and call `scrollIntoView()` on it, which brings the `<div>` into the viewport.

Comment: No it does not work. The link is intercepted by the <iron-pages> and the browser does not jump to the div

Comment: Ok, that wasn't part of your original question :)

Comment: @user2447161 Updated answer based on new details from question

Comment: I had to edit it a bit to keep supporting normal links, but it works like a charm ! many thanks !